# unable to save the data to the json using post

Tags: swift3

I m unable to save the data back to json which is written in text fields and when save button is clicked it have to save the updated data to json.
Here is the code i have written on save button action:

```
if let id = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "NgoId"){
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.shreetechnosolution.com/funded/ngo_profile.php?ngoid=\(id)")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "Nameofngo=\(textngoname.text!)&NameofChiefFunctionary=\(textcheiffunction.text!)&NameofChairman=\(textchairman.text!)&NameofSeceratary=\(textsecratary.text!)&NameofTreasurer=\(texttreasurer.text!)&ParentOrganization=\(textparentorg.text!)&AboutNGO=\(Textngo.text)&photoofNGO=\(imageviewngo.image)&ngoid=\(id)&value=NGO"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error ?? "" as! Error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(String(describing: response))")

        }
            let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! NSDictionary
            let msg = json.value(forKey: "message") as! NSString!



            let alert : UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Alert box!", message: "\(msg!).",delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            alert.show()
        }
        task.resume()
        }
```

Comment: can you show me log what your httpStatus code is. And gimme one sample NgoId key to test.

Answer (score 0):

Try following way of post data code, this will help you. And always try use try-catch to get error. Below is your working code with response.

```
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(1, forKey: "NgoId");

    if let id = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "NgoId"){
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.shreetechnosolution.com/funded/ngo_profile.php?ngoid=\(id)")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        var postJson = Dictionary<String, Any>.init();
        postJson["Nameofngo"] = "NONAME";
        postJson["NameofChiefFunctionary"] = "";
        postJson["NameofChairman"] = "";
        postJson["NameofSeceratary"] = "";
        postJson["NameofTreasurer"] = "";
        postJson["ParentOrganization"] = "";
        postJson["AboutNGO"] = "";
        postJson["ngoid"] = id;
        postJson["value"] = "NGO";

        print("post json \(postJson)");

        do {
           let postData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postJson, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted);
            request.httpBody = postData;
        }catch let err {
            print("exception is \(err)");
        }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let responseData = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error ?? "" as! Error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
            }

            let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: []) as! NSDictionary

            print("json response \(json)");
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Response In log-----

```
{
    listngoprofile =     (
                {
            AboutNGO = "<null>";
            City = "<null>";
            CityofRegisteration = "<null>";
            CompleteAddress = "<null>";
            Country = "<null>";
            DateofRegisteration = "<null>";
            Declaration = 1;
            EmailID = "hgmaetrust@gmail.com";
            FCRADateofRegisteration = "";
            FCRARegisterationNo = "";
            FCRAValidUpto = "19/07/2025";
            "Fax_No" = "<null>";
            Issues =             (
                                {
                    Issues = "Education& Scholarship";
                },
                                {
                    Issues = fdfsdfasdfdsd;
                },
                                {
                    Issues = kdjkdsksd;
                },
                                {
                    Issues = dfjkkdf;
                }
            );
            Majorachievements = "<null>";
            MobileNo = 9922400698;
            NGOBankAccountNo = "<null>";
            NGOBankAccounttype = "<null>";
            NGOBankIFSCCode = "<null>";
            NameinBankAccount = "<null>";
            NameofChairman = "<null>";
            NameofChiefFunctionary = "<null>";
            NameofSeceratary = "<null>";
            NameofTreasurer = "<null>";
            Nameofngo = "<null>";
            NgoID = 1;
            ParentOrganization = "<null>";
            Pincode = "<null>";
            Regcertimg = "<null>";
            RegisterationNo = "<null>";
            Registeredwith = "<null>";
            State = "<null>";
            StateofRegisteration = "<null>";
            "TelePhone_No" = "<null>";
            TypeofNGO = "<null>";
            Validupto = "<null>";
            WebsiteURL = "<null>";
            YearofEstablishment = "<null>";
            keyOperational =             (
                                {
                    Area = Maharashtra;
                },
                                {
                    Area = dfsdfdfsdfsdfdsfdsfdsfds;
                },
                                {
                    Area = kjdjdkjdfjl;
                },
                                {
                    Area = jldklk;
                }
            );
            photoofNGO = "<null>";
        }
    );
    success = 1;
}
```

If you want to apply check for `<null>` values in response, then follow below code for check.

```
    if let successVal = response?["success"] as? NSNumber {
        uWillGetValueHere = successVal;
    }
```

Comment: actually i m not setting the value here i want that id when i login to my app i have stored it in id variable already and those text field you have caheched in poststring "" to be null are having values in case then what could be done

Comment: then use your id variable, I am also using your id variable by using following line, UserDefaults.standard.setValue(1, forKey: "NgoId");